# The compiler cannot find my 'getters'

Tags: java

I am modeling a baseball team with both a Player class and a Team class.  Player has a few of each player's statistics (name, number, batting average, etc.), and Team has an array of Player objects, the team name and the size of the team.

I created an array of Player objects in Team.java, and used a simple 'for' loop to search through my array.  However, I get multiple compile time errors that say that the compiler cannot find any of my 'getters' that are in Player.java.

Here is my battingAverage method that uses such a loop in Team.java:

```
public double battingAverage () {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        sum = sum + team[i].getAverage;
    }
    return (sum / size);
}
```

And here is the 'getter' in Player.java

```
public double getAverage () {
    return average;
}
```

(average is declared as a private dynamic field and is given a value by the constructor)

This is the error the compiler gives me:

```
./Team.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable getAverage
location: class Player
        sum = sum + team[i].getAverage;
                           ^
```

This type of error repeats for all of the 'getters' that I use in Team.java (getPosition, getName, etc.).

However, I know that the compiler recognizes team[i] as a singular Player object because I also get the following error:

```
    ./Team.java:21: operator + cannot be applied to double,Player.getAverage
            sum = sum + team[i].getAverage;
                  ^
```

So it seems to me that for some reason, getAverage just cannot be found in Player.java and I cannot figure out why.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
sum = sum + team[i].getAverage;
```

use

```
sum = sum + team[i].getAverage();
```

It is a method with no parameters you are calling and not a public field you are accessing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
sum = sum + team[i].getAverage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You left out the parentheses when you called getAverage in the loop.  All method calls must be followed by parentheses, even if they do not take arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You are not a accessing property, rather you are calling a method. so that's why that error is showing. `change sum = sum + team[i].getAverage;` to this `sum = sum + team[i].getAverage();`

Comment: Thank you! I stared at my computer for an hour and now I feel dumb. It is always the little things.

Comment: if it help, feel free to click the up button and the check mark :)